# Corda 4 - Querying vault by specific transactionid

Tags: corda

We are building a POC using Corda 4 and Springboot web server.

We are currently using the following code to retrieve all the states from the vault via RPC -

```
    val vaultStatesAndRefs = services.proxy.vaultQueryBy<State>().states
    val vaultStates = vaultStatesAndRefs.map { it.state.data }
```

We want - to retrieve a state from the vault via RPC using the ***transactionId***.

Kindly guide in achieving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that Corda doesn't guarantee the set of transactions retrieved via any method would remain consistent across future versions of Corda. This is because the future version of Corda would use SGX-encrypted format to exchange transaction chain between nodes. Thus the transactions can only be decrypted in a secure SGX enclave.

Having said that there is no direct API exposed which could be used to obtain state based on transactionId via RPC. The one you could use (`internalFindVerifiedTransaction`) have been deprecated and would likely be removed in the future versions of Corda.

The way to do this I suppose would be to use flow. You could retrieve the output states based on the `transactionId`.

```
SignedTransaction tx = getServiceHub().getValidatedTransactions().getTransaction(
           SecureHash.parse(txId));
tx.toLedgerTransaction(getServiceHub()).getOutputStates();
```

You could then trigger the flow from your client using RPC and get the result from the `FlowHandle` object returned.

```
FlowHandle<List<ContractState>> flowHandle =
            proxy.startFlowDynamic(GetStateFlow.class, txId);
List<ContractState> list =  flowHandle.getReturnValue().get();
```